# How to specify c header file in android.mk file

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i had a c source folder name "clib" and in that , i have some example files like 1.h ,1.c , 2.h ,2.c,3.c,3.h and out side that folder i have 4.h , 4.c , 4_jni.h , 4_jni.c

Now to build ".so" i created my android.mk something like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH) 
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH) 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := clib
TIME_SYNC_PATH := ../../../clib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \ 
                    4_jni.c \
                    4.c     \
                    $(TIME_SYNC_PATH)/1.c \
                    $(TIME_SYNC_PATH)/2.c \
                    $(TIME_SYNC_PATH)/3.c \
$(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Here 4.h includes 1.h file**

So my real problem is when i tried to build .so file it gives me a error some like this

**`fatal error: 1.h: No such file or directory`**

if i remove the 1.h from 4.h , everything is building fine , but i had a large c library 
with same kind of folder structure , and some of .h file contains few marcos defined ....

So Please any suggestion how to include  .h which is in different folder..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to specify a `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` location.

This variable holds the locations of your header files like :

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/include/
```

You can of course specify multiple locations :

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/project2/src/include/
```

Note that when this variable is evaluated by the `ndk-build` utility, its value is considered to be relative to `$(LOCAL_PATH)`, so you need to use `$(LOCAL_PATH)` when giving a path in `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/(path of the .h files)