# Android Studio include cpp headers

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, native, header-files

CMake can not determine linker language for target: CydiaSubstrate … is the error I am getting. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong nor can I find anything related to adding headers through cmake. Please refer to the code below:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         platinmods

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/platinmods.cpp )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         CydiaSubstrate

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/CydiaSubstrate.h )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   platinmods

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   CydiaSubstrate

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: `CydiaSubstrate.h` is your header file right?

Comment: yes it is my header file

Comment: Why don't you include it in your c++ file by using `#include<CydiaSubstrate.h>` ? I mean not include it in Cmake file bro, but in `platinmods.cpp`

Comment: I did but it cannot locate the file

Comment: your c++ file and header file stay in the same path or not bro??

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353009/how-to-specify-c-header-file-in-android-mk-file) and [this link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/258) can help you bro.

Comment: Please provide the 2nd link as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: it worked right bro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake cannot determine linker language for target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655705/cmake-cannot-determine-linker-language-for-target)

Comment: You attempt to create a library consisting only from a *header*. First of all, this is very *unusual* library. Then, CMake determine languageaccording to extensions of the *source* files. (E.g., if all sources have `.c` extension, CMake assumes C language, if some source has `.cpp` extension, CMake assumes CXX language, and so on). But without sources at all CMake cannot deduce the language. This is described in the referenced question and it answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code is trying to build 2 libraries: platinmods and CydiaSubstrate. But if your intension is just to let CydiaSubstrate.h used by platinmods.cpp, your code is not doing what you want. Guessing you want later indeed,

- In source code, do `#include "CydiaSubstrate.h"`, and copy your CydiaSubstrate.h into the same directory as platinmods.cpp
- Only leave platinmod related code inside build.gradle, delete all CydiaSubstrate related lines
- If your header file is not in the same folder as your source file, use CMake's [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html)() like [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L41)
- If you are having source code backing up that header file,  you need to add that source file into compile too ( same as platinmods.cpp )
- do open CydiaSubstrate.h to see what macro is needed to be defined to use it, that helps.

then do a build->clean, and build ->build apk to see what the problems left ( and fix them ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this link which already closed in [android-ndk](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/258) sample or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16353474/7257373) by `Halim Qarroum` in other related post.

Hope it can help you.